# Eternality of vedas on the basis of Shabda (word) as per Purva Mimansa

Tags: vedas, jaimini, apaurusheyatva

In Jaimini Mimansa sutra one of the objections raised against eternality of vedas is:-

> By reason of no stability. (Sutra 7)
>
> The objector says that there is no stability of the word as
> soon as it is pronounced, it vanishes.

but i'm not able to understand the response given:-

> Disappearance after once coming into existence is by reason of object not coming into contact.

Could someone explain it in detail manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know from where you are reading those words, but Ganganath Jha's translation of Shabara's Bhashya uses clear English.

[Sutra 13](https://archive.org/details/ShabaraBhasyaTrByGanganathJha/Shabara%20Bhasya%20tr%20by%20Ganganath%20Jha%20Vol%201/page/n47/mode/1up) has the Siddhanta response to the Purvapaksha in sutra 7:

> "What happens (when the word ceases to be heard) is that there is no perception of the extant (word) on account of the non-reaching of the object [the word] (by the manifesting agency)."

Shabara in his commentary for this sutra says that the word is actually always existing, but only manifestation of it for perception differs: one hears the word at some times, but other times he does not hear it. In other words, he hears it when it is being pronounced, and does not here it when it is not being pronounced.

Comment: According to you "he hears it when it is being pronounced, and does not hear it when it is not being pronounced. " But the objector is saying  even if the word is pronounced it ceases to exist after some time.

Comment: @dark_prince Yes and the siddhanta response to that objection is that the word continues to exist, but that it is simply not heard by people.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "but that it is simply not heard by people". If word exists then why it is not being heard? Does it imply that vibrations(sound) of word ceases to exist?

Comment: @dark_prince "Does it imply that vibrations(sound) of word ceases to exist?" - yes, that is exactly what the commentary says.

Comment: @dark_prince - when you make a glass bottle and then break it - the bottle may be gone, but you can create it again - because in your **mind**, the idea of a glass bottle exists. similarly, the world may cease to exist, but the idea of the world (how to create it, how to populate it etc. all of which is there in Vedas) always exists in Brahman's mind.